# ASP.NET Using Images instead HyperLinks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx page called `bookscategory.aspx` with this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <p>Books list</p>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Category") %>'></asp:Literal></h3>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Reviews") %>' ItemType="ELibraryModel.Review">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Title%>' NavigateUrl='<%# "../books/bookdetails.aspx?bookId=" + Item.Id.ToString() %>'>
                </asp:HyperLink><br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
using (ELibraryEntities entities = new ELibraryEntities())
{
    var allbooks = from books in entities.Books.Include("Reviews")
                         orderby books.Category
                         select new { books.Category, books.Reviews};
    Repeater1.DataSource = allbooks;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

Now on my Default.aspx page I have a book image:

```
<div class="prod_img">
   <img src="../Images/asp.net_image.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>
</div>

<div class="box_center">
        <div class="prod_title">ASP.NET Book</div>
            <p class="details">ASP.NET Book.</p>
            <a href="bookscategory.aspx" class="more">- read more -</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Finally, when I click on this image I want to navigate to that exact review:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "../books/bookdetails.aspx?ReviewId=" + Item.Id.ToString()
```

Everything works fine with `asp:HyperLink`-s but instead I want to use images.

I'm reading Beginning ASP.NET 4.5 in C# and VB and here you can see all reviews  http://aspnet45.planetwrox.com/Reviews/All.aspx. I want to use Images instead HyperLinks.

Comment: why don't you put an <img> inside your <a> ?

Comment: Please do not create [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666587)... you should **edit** your original question

Answer (score 1):

`HyperLink` control already provides this capabilty - it has [ImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.imageurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, and when this is set, `HyperLink` appears as an image:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1"
               NavigateUrl='<%# "../books/bookdetails.aspx?ReviewId=" + Item.Id.ToString() %>'
               ImageUrl="~/url/to/image" />
```

Comment: Yes, but each review should have a different image! If I do this now all reviews have the same image.

Comment: @user2969489, absolutely not necessary. You can compute the image url inline, or in code behind, or pull it from database. Where does image come from in your case?

Comment: I think that's my biggest problem. I don't know from where to get Images and how. I have a folder called Images on my project. Should I get them programmatically or...I don't know.

Comment: @user2969489, you can link them from the pages (or css classes), as simple as "~/Images/image_name". However you have to decide the rule on which you will assign images to review - nobody can do it for you, since this is a matter of project requirements

Comment: Thanks for help Andrei, but where to assign each review an image? In bookscategory.aspx or Default.aspx? I'm new to ASP.NET and I have no idea how to start assigning images to reviews. As you said, with ImageUrl on asp:HyperLink all reviews gets the same image.

Comment: @user2969489, this has little to nothing to do with ASP.NET. Suppose you have a review, and you need to display an image for it. How to know which image to use? It can be some connection between image name and review (say image name is review title), or review can have property ImagePath pointing to the image, or it can be just random. What are your requirements regarding this?

Comment: You're right, that's my requirement but I don't know how to do it through coding and that's why I'm asking here if someone can give me an idea how to start with the code.

Comment: Any help with the coding?

Comment: @user2969489, of course not, this is your project (or maybe even job assignment). Start coding yourself, and if you have specific problems - post them at SO to get the answers.